# How to inject a JSF bean into a spring bean

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-mvc, spring-security, jsf-1.2

I'm working on a legacy JSF application which we are slowly porting over to Spring MVC. We are using Spring Security to control login information. After logging the user in, the JSF pages globally instantiate a session scoped bean that is used *everywhere*. I'd like to change the application so that we can go to a page that was developed with Spring MVC first.

One approach I tried was to convert the bean into a spring bean and have it injected into JSF, but unfortunately that turned out to require a lot of changes to the bean to make it possible. One possible hack I thought of is to add a special redirecting JSF page to initialize the JSF beans before sending the user to the Spring MVC page. That seems like quite a bit of a hack though so I'm looking for another solution.

Is there some other way that I can force the session scoped bean to be initialized before I go to my Spring pages so that I can just pull the bean out of session?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring MVC, you can make your "bean" a Model Attribute, then have it auto-loaded into session using a combination of annotations on the Controller, handler methods, and a method that creates an instance of your bean.  Your controller would look something like this:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"myBean"})
@RequestMapping("/myPath")
public class MyController {
  @RequestMapping("/myPath2")
  public String myHandler(@ModelAttribute("myBean") MyBean myBean) {
    // ...do stuff, return view
  }

  @ModelAttribute("myBean")
  MyBean createMyBean() {
    // Create and init an instance
    return new MyBean();
  }
}
```

You will get a MyBean magically created for you whenever there isn't one, and any time you update the Model (or ModelAndView) with "myBean", it will also get magically added to the Session.

Comment: I tried that at first. Unfortunately, this particular bean has a bunch of dependencies on other JSF beans and the JSF message context. It seemed like quite a bit of work to do. I'm really hoping to get rid of this bean eventually, but it's connected to almost everything!

Comment: Well, thats the most "Spring-ish" way to do it.  Other than that, if it's already in session, you could skip the "createXXX" method and just use it directly out of the HttpSession.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want to do but JSF doesn't initialize the bean until you go to a jsf page that asks for it. :(

Comment: You can have jsf create the bean for you without redirection. Check this web site for a solution from Balus.